# How to get cart price rule collection in magento 2?

Tags: catalog, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules, magento2.2.4, price-rules

I want to show cart price rule on product page. How to get collection of cart price rules?

Answer (score 2):

try this way.. this code working for me

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product_discamt = 0;
$objrules = $objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory')->create();
$rules = $objrules->getCollection();
foreach ($rules as $tmprule) {
          $rule = $objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule')->load($tmprule->getId());
          $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());
          $item = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
          $item->setProduct($product);                                
          if ($rule->getActions()->validate($item) && $rule->getIsActive()) {
              $product_discamt=$rule->getDiscountAmount();
          }
  }

  if($product_discamt>0){?>

  <span class="cart-rule">-<?php echo round($product_discamt);?><span class="cart-rule-percentage">%</span></span>
</div>
}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

namespace Veera\Sales\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\CollectionFactory as RuleCollection;

class Validatecode extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var RuleCollection
     */
    protected $_ruleCollection;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param RuleCollection $ruleCollection
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context        $context,
        RuleCollection $ruleCollection
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_ruleCollection = $ruleCollection;
    }

    /**
     * @return false
     * @throws \Zend_Db_Select_Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var Collection $collection */
        $rules = $this->_ruleCollection->create();
        $rules->setValidationFilter($websiteId, $customer->getGroupId(), trim($post['code']))
            ->addFieldToFilter('rule_coupons.code', ['notnull' => true])
            ->addFieldToFilter('rule_coupons.times_used', 0)
            ->load();

        return false;
    }
}
```